# If $ F(x,\bullet) \in {L^{\infty}}(G,B) $ for all $ x \in G $, then is $ x \mapsto F(x,\bullet) $ strongly measurable?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, topological-groups, haar-measure

Let $ (X,\Sigma,\mu) $ be a $ \sigma $-finite measure space and $ B $ a Banach space. A function $ f: X \to B $ is said to be **strongly $ \mu $-measurable** iff it is the *almost-everywhere* pointwise limit of a sequence $ (s_{n}: X \to B)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ of integrable simple functions, where an integrable simple function $ s: X \to B $ has the form
$$
s = \sum_{(E,b) \in I} \chi_{E} \cdot b
$$
for some finite subset $ I $ of $ \{ E \in \Sigma \mid \mu(E) < \infty \} \times B $.

Let $ G $ be a second-countable, locally compact Hausdorff group and $ \mu_{G} $ a fixed Haar measure on the Borel $ \sigma $-algebra $ \mathscr{B}(G) $ of $ G $. The second-countability condition implies that $ G $ is $ \sigma $-compact, which ensures that $ (G,\mathscr{B}(G),\mu_{G}) $ is a $ \sigma $-finite measure space. Let $ B $ be a *separable* Banach space and $ {L^{\infty}}(G,B) $ the set of all (equivalence classes of) $ B $-norm essentially bounded strongly $ \mu_{G} $-measurable functions from $ G $ to $ B $.

**Note:** $ {L^{\infty}}(G,B) $ is a Banach space, and except in trivial cases, it is always non-separable.

> **Question.** If $ F: G \times G \to B $ is a strongly $ \mu_{G \times G} $-measurable function where $ F(x,\bullet) \in {L^{\infty}}(G,B) $ for all $ x \in G $, then is it true that the mapping
>   \begin{align}
> G & \to     {L^{\infty}}(G,B); \\
> x & \mapsto F(x,\bullet)
> \end{align}
>   is strongly $ \mu $-measurable?

Thank you all very much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is **no**, even in the case of $G:=\mathbb{R}$ with the Lebesgue measure and $B: =\mathbb{R}$ as a Banach space.

Let $F: \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ be the characteristic function of the half-plane above the diagonal: $F(x,y):=\chi_\mathbb{{R}_+}(y-x)$. So $F\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R} )$; however the corresponding map $\tilde F: \mathbb{R}  \to L^\infty(\mathbb{R} )$ such that $x\mapsto F(x,\cdot)=\chi_{[x,\infty)}$  is not strongly measurable, because its range is not separable, as it is the discrete uncountable set $\{\chi_{[x,\infty)} : x\in \mathbb{R}\}$ (not even if we modify $\tilde F$ on some Lebesgue null set).

**Rmk 1**. A Banach space valued strongly measurable map $f$ on a measure space $X$    is necessarily  *essentially separable* , that is, up to removing a null set $N\subset X$, its image $f(X\setminus N)$ is a separable subset of $B$ (indeed it is included in the closure of the countable union of the images of the simple functions that converge pointwise to $f$; and a simple function is exactly a measurable function with finite range).

**Rmk 2**. A theorem of Pettis states that a Banach space valued   map $f$ on a measure space $X$ is strongly measurable if and only if:  (i)  *it is essentially separable*; (ii) *it is weakly measurable* (that is, measurable w.r.to the $\sigma$ algebra generated by the weak topology; (iii) *its support is $\sigma$-finite.* (See e.g. the Kōsaku Yosida's *Functional Analysis*. The proof is easy. ).

Comment: I think Yosida quotes Pettis' theorem with a reference for the proof. Anyway note that "strongly measurable" easily implies (i), (ii) and (iii); for the other implication, one can assume $X$  sigma-finite and B separable. Note also that in a separable Banach space any closed ball is a countable intersection of open half-spaces, therefore it is weakly measurable, so that the weak and the strong Borel algebras coincide.

Comment: Thank you very much, Pietro. I need some time to look over your solution. One quick question: If I replace $ L^{\infty} $ by $ L^{2} $, do I get an affirmative answer?

Comment: I think so. For measure spaces $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ and $(Y,\mathcal{B},\nu)$, for a Banach space $B$, and for $1\le p <\infty$ the correspondence gives a normed space isomorphism between the Bochner spaces $$L^p(X\times Y,B)\to L^p(X,L^p(Y,B)).$$
This is essentially Fubini-Tonelli; the key point is that a dense subset of simple functions in $L^p(X\times Y,B)$ is obtained by using characteristic functions of *rectangles* of finite measure in $X\times Y$; and these are mapped on a dense set of simple functions in $L^p(X,L^p(Y,B))$. I think no further assumptions are needed on $X$, $Y$, $B$.

Comment: Hi Pietro. Actually, I’m not sure about your last comment, as I’m only assuming that $ F: X \times Y \to B $ is strongly measurable and not that it belongs to $ {L^{p}}(X \times Y,B) $ for any $ p \geq 1 $.

Comment: Sorry, I understood replacing $L^\infty$ by $L^2$ was referred to the statement in my answer.

Comment: It’s okay. I just thought that if I replaced $ L^{\infty} $ by $ L^{2} $ in the statement of the problem, then things would be easier, but it seems not.

Comment: For  $1\le p<\infty$, your hypotheses should ensure that $L^p(G,B)$   be separable ; so you only need to verify condition (ii) of Pettis'theorem...

Comment: Thinking about your previous [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/184649/if-fx-bullet-in-l-inftyg-b-for-all-x-in-g-then-is-x-maps?rq=1#comment461412_184653), I feel that the case $p=\infty$ can not hold because we lost almost all convergence theorems in that case... In my [proof](https://mathoverflow.net/a/452821/99469) for the case $p \in [1, \infty)$, I used two lemmas which are about convergent sequences.