# Is there a modification of $f$ on a null set such that $F: [0, T] \to L^p ({\mathbb R}^d), t \mapsto f(t,\cdot)$ is Bochner measurable?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions

Let $T>0$ and $p \in [1, \infty)$. Let $f \in L^p ([0, T] \times {\mathbb R}^d)$. By a theorem in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4301414/if-f-n-is-cauchy-and-converges-a-e-to-f-there-is-a-cauchy-subsequence) thread, there is a Lebesgue null subset $N$ of $[0, T]$ such that $f(t, \cdot)$ is Lebesgue measurable and that $f(t, \cdot) \in L^p ({\mathbb R}^d)$ for all $t \in [0, T] \setminus N$. For $t \in N$, we don't know the measurability and thus the integrability of $f(t, \cdot)$. However, we can re-define $f$ such that $f(t, \cdot) \equiv 0$ for all $t \in N$. Then writing $f(t, \cdot) \in L^p ({\mathbb R}^d)$ is rigorously valid for *every* $t \in [0, T]$.

> Is there a modification of $f$ on a Lebesgue null subset of $[0, T]$ such that the map
> $$
> F: [0, T] \to L^p ({\mathbb R}^d), t \mapsto f(t, \cdot)
> $$
> is [Bochner measurable](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bochner_measurable_function)?

Intuitively, the answer is positive. But I don't know how to prove it...

Comment: It seems a simpler proof can be found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/184748/if-fx-bullet-in-l2g-b-for-all-x-in-g-then-is-x-mapsto-f).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let

- $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ and $(Y, \mathcal B, \nu)$ be complete $\sigma$-finite measure spaces, and $(E, | \cdot |)$ a Banach space.
- $S (X)$ the space of $\mu$-simple functions from $X$ to $E$.
- $\mathcal C :=\mathcal A \otimes \mathcal B$ the product $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$.
- $\lambda := \mu \otimes \nu$ the product measure of $\mu$ and $\nu$.

Here we use Bochner integral. Then we have

> Let $p \in [1, \infty)$.
>
> - [Lemma 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4737770/tensor-product-of-lp-spaces-is-dense-in-the-product-lp-space) Then
>   $$
>   \overline{S(X) \otimes S(Y)} =  L^p(X \times Y),
>   $$
>   where the closure is with respect to the norm in $L^p(X \times Y)$. Here $S (X) \otimes S(Y)$ is identified with a subspace of  $L^p(X \times Y)$ through the natural embedding
>   $$
>   f \otimes g  \mapsto \big( (x,y) \mapsto f(x) g(y) \big).
>   $$
> - [Lemma 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4301414/if-f-n-is-cauchy-and-converges-a-e-to-f-there-is-a-cauchy-subsequence) Let $(f_n) \subset S (X \times Y)$ be a Cauchy sequence in $L^p(X \times Y)$ that converges $\lambda$-a.e. to $f$.  Then there is a subsequence $\varphi$ of $\mathbb N$ such that for $\mu$-a.e. $x \in X$, we have $(f_{\varphi (n)} (x, \cdot))_n \subset S (Y)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L^p (Y)$ and converges to $f(x, \cdot)$ both $\nu$-a.e. and in $L^p (Y)$.

Let $X := [0, T]$ and $Y := \mathbb R^d$. Let $\mathcal A, \mathcal B$ be the corresponding Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebras of $X$ and $Y$. Let $\mu, \nu$ be the corresponding Lebesgue measures on $X, Y$.

By **Lemma 1**, there is a sequence of $(f_n) \subset L^p(X \times Y)$ with $f_n = g_n h_n$ for some $g_n \in S (X)$ and $h_n \in S (Y)$ such that $\|f_n-f\|_{L^p(X \times Y)} \to 0$. Clearly, $(f_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $S(X \times Y)$. Also, each $f_n$ is of the form
$$
f_n (t, x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\varphi_n} e_{n, k} 1_{A_{n, k}} (t) 1_{B_{n, k}} (x)
\quad \forall t\in X, x \in Y,
$$
for some $e_{n, k} \in \mathbb R$ and $A_{n, k} \in \mathcal A, B_{n, k} \in \mathcal B$ such that $\mu(A_{n, k}) + \nu (B_{n, k}) < \infty$. Then $f_n (t, \cdot) \in L^p(Y)$ for all $t \in X$. Let
$$
F_n : X \to L^p (Y), t \mapsto f_n (t, \cdot)
\quad \forall n \in \mathbb N.
$$

Clearly, $F_n \in S(X, L^p(Y)) \subset  L^p(X, L^p(Y))$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. By Fubini's theorem,
$$
\begin{align*}
\| F_n - F_m\|_{L^p(X, L^p(Y))}^p &= \int_0^T \mathrm d t \, \|F_n (t) - F_m (t)\|_{L^p (Y)}^p \\
&= \|f_n-f_m\|_{L^p(X \times Y)}^p.
\end{align*}
$$

Then $(F_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in the Banach space $L^p(X, L^p(Y))$. Then there is $F \in L^p(X, L^p(Y))$ such that $\|F_n-F\|_{L^p(X, L^p(Y))} \to 0$.

Convergence in $L^p$ implies a.e. convergence of a subsequence, so WLOG we assume $f_n \to f$ $\lambda$ a.e. and $F_n \to F$ $\mu$-a.e. By **Lemma 2**, there is a subsequence $\varphi$ of $\mathbb N$ su for $\mu$-a.e. $t \in X$ we have
$$
\|f_{\varphi (n)} (t, \cdot)-f(t, \cdot) \|_{L^p (Y)} \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0.
$$

On the other hand, for $\mu$-a.e. $t \in X$ we have
$$
\|f_n (t, \cdot) - F (t)\|_{L^p(Y)} =\|F_n (t) - F (t)\|_{L^p(Y)} \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0.
$$

It follows that for $\mu$-a.e. $t \in X$ we have
$$
\|f (t, \cdot) - F(t) \|_{L^p (Y)} = 0.
$$

The claim then follows.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by two answers in [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/184748/if-fx-bullet-in-l2g-b-for-all-x-in-g-then-is-x-mapsto-f) thread, I'm able to drop the assumption on the integrability of $f$, i.e.,

> **Theorem** Let $p \in [1, \infty)$ and $f \in L^0 (Z)$ such that
> $$
> f(x, \cdot) \in L^p(Y)
> \quad \text{for}\quad \mu \text{-a.e. } x\in X.
> \tag{$*$}
> $$
> Then $f \in L^0(X, L^p(Y))$.

My below proof adds nothing new to the other answers. I just fill in the details to fix the ideas.

---

Below we use [Bochner measurability](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bochner_measurable_function) and [Bochner integral](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bochner_integral). Let

- $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ and $(Y, \mathcal B, \nu)$ be complete $\sigma$-finite measure spaces,
- $(E, | \cdot |)$ a Banach space,
- $S (X)$ the space of $\mu$-simple functions from $X$ to $E$,
- $L^0 (X)$ the space of $\mu$-measurable functions from $X$ to $E$,
- $L^1 (X)$ the space of $\mu$-integrable functions from $X$ to $E$,
- $Z := X \times Y$,
- $\mathcal C :=\mathcal A \otimes \mathcal B$ the product $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$,
- $\lambda := \mu \otimes \nu$ the product measure of $\mu$ and $\nu$,
- $(Z, \overline{\mathcal C}, \overline{\lambda})$ the completion of $(Z, \mathcal C, \lambda)$.

First, we have

> [Lemma 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4753844/let-f-in-l0x-times-y-then-for-mu-a-e-x-in-x-we-have-fx-cdot?noredirect=1&lq=1) If $f \in L^0 (Z)$ then $f(x, \cdot) \in L^0(Y)$ for $\mu$-a.e. $x\in X$.
>
> [Lemma 2](https://mathoverflow.net/a/452953/477203) Let $f \in S (Z)$ and $\varepsilon>0$. There is $f_\varepsilon \in S(Z)$ of the form
> $$
> f_\varepsilon (x, y) = \sum_{i,j=1}^{n} e_{i,j} 1_{A_{i}} (x) 1_{B_{j}} (y)
> $$
> such that
>
> - $(A_{i})_{i=1}^{n}, (B_{j})_{j=1}^{n}$ are measurable partitions of $X,Y$ respectively,
> - $e_{ij} \in E$ and $\mu(A_i)+\nu(B_j) < \infty$ for all $i,j \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$,
> - $\|f-f_\varepsilon\|_{L^1(Z)} < \varepsilon$, and
> - $\lambda (\{f \neq f_\varepsilon\}) < \varepsilon$.

By modifying $f$ on a null set, we can assume $(*)$ for all $x\in X$.

There is a sequence $(g_n) \subset S(X\times Y)$ such that $\|g_n-f\|_{L^1(Z)} < \frac{1}{n}$ and $g_n \to f$ $\lambda$-a.e. For each $n$, let $f_n$ be the approximating function of $g_n$ given by **Lemma 2** such that $\|f_n-g_n\|_{L^1(Z)} < 2^{-n}$ and $\lambda (\{f_n \neq g_n\}) < 2^{-n}$. It's easy to see that $\|f_n-f\|_{L^1(Z)} < \frac{2}{n}$ and $f_n \to f$ $\lambda$-a.e. Let
$$
f_n (x, y) = \sum_{i,j=1}^{\varphi_n} e_{n, i,j} 1_{A_{n, i}} (x) 1_{B_{n, j}} (y).
$$

1. First, we consider the case $\nu (Y) < \infty$ and $\alpha := \sup_{(x, y) \in X \times Y} |f (x, y)| +1< \infty$. Let
   $$
   e'_{n,i,j} :=
   \begin{cases}
   e_{n, i, j} &\text{if} \quad |e_{n, i, j}| \le \alpha, \\
   0 &\text{otherwise},
   \end{cases}
   $$
   and
   $$
   f'_n (x, y) := \sum_{i,j=1}^{\varphi_n} e'_{n, i,j} 1_{A_{n, i}} (x) 1_{B_{n, j}} (y).
   $$

Clearly, $f'_n \in S(Z)$ and $f'_n \to f$ $\lambda$-a.e. I already [proved](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4753844/let-f-in-l0x-times-y-then-for-mu-a-e-x-in-x-we-have-fx-cdot) that for $\mu$-a.e. $x \in X$:
$$
\begin{align*}
f'_n(x, \cdot) \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} f(x, \cdot) \quad \nu \text{-a.e.}
\end{align*}
$$

By dominated convergence [theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4298588/dominated-convergence-theorem-for-banach-space), for $\mu$-a.e. $x \in X$: $\|f'_n(x, \cdot) - f(x, \cdot) \|_{L^p(Y)} \to 0$. Let
$$
F_n: X \to L^p(Y), x \mapsto f'_n(x, \cdot), \\
F: X \to L^p(Y), x \mapsto f(x, \cdot).
$$

Clearly, $F_n \in S(X, L^p(Y))$ for all $n$. The $\mu$-a.e. limit of a sequence of $\mu$-measurable functions [is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4507762/generalize-a-theorem-about-the-mu-measurability-of-a-mu-a-e-limit-of-a-se) again $\mu$-measurable. It suffices to prove that for $\mu$-a.e. $x \in X$: $\|F_n (x)-F(x)\|_{L^p(Y)} \to 0$, which we have already done.

2. Second, we consider the case $\alpha < \infty$. Because $(Y, \mathcal B, \nu)$ is $\sigma$-finite, there is a countable measurable partition $(Y_n)$ of $Y$ with $\sup_n \nu(Y_n) < \infty$. We apply part (1) for each function $f_n := f1_{X \times Y_n}$ and get $f_n \in L^0 (Z)$. Clearly, $\sum_{k=1}^n f_k \to f$ everywhere. The $\lambda$-a.e. limit of a sequence of $\lambda$-measurable functions [is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4507762/generalize-a-theorem-about-the-mu-measurability-of-a-mu-a-e-limit-of-a-se) again $\lambda$-measurable. Then $f \in L^0 (Z)$.
3. Finally, we also drop the assumption $\alpha < \infty$. Let $Z_n := \{n \le |f| < n+1 \}$ for $n \in \mathbb N$. It is not necessarily true that $Z_n \in \cal C$, but we always have $Z_n \in \overline{\cal C}$. Clearly, $(Z_n)_n$ is a partition of $Z$. We apply part (2) for each function $f_n := f1_{Z_n}$ and get $f_n \in L^0 (Z)$. Clearly, $\sum_{k=1}^n f_k \to f$ everywhere. The $\lambda$-a.e. limit of a sequence of $\lambda$-measurable functions [is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4507762/generalize-a-theorem-about-the-mu-measurability-of-a-mu-a-e-limit-of-a-se) again $\lambda$-measurable. Then $f \in L^0 (Z)$.

This completes the proof!